# Unity2D - Non Uniform Jump, Jumping Too High

Tags: c#, unity3d-2dtools

I'm building a 2D platforming game in Unity 5 for school using C#. Sometimes, when my character goes to jump the jump is incredibly high. It doesn't happen with any regularity or in any particular placement. At first I was using AddForce and then I tried to just change the Y velocity on the rigidbody2D but it didn't fix the problem. I moved the jump code from Update to FixedUpdate but that only made the jump less responsive. I'm using GetKeyDown so that the force is not applied the entire time the key is down. I've used Debug.Log and run several tests to make sure that the jump code is not executing multiple times per key press. I read that it could have something to do with how the ground is detected but I can set grounded to false in several places in the jump code but it still does not help. I've moved the code used to detect ground from FixedUpdate to Update to LateUpdate but to no avail. Below is my jump code and the code I am using to detect ground.

```
in LateUpdate() grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);               //Use proper variables to check for ground and set grounded bool accordingly

in Update()//JUMPING-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (grounded &&                                     //If the player is on the ground,
        Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) &&              //and the jump button is pressed,
        RanaAnim.GetBool("Blocking") == false &&        //and Rana is not blocking, 
        !attacking)                                     //or performing an attack
        //&& GameManager.InputAllowed)                  //and the game is not paused...
    {
        if (GameManager.characterSwitch)                                    //If Rana is the active character...
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = RanaJump;         //Prime Rana's jump audio clip
            gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();                  //Play Rana's jump audio clip
        }
        else                                                                //If Haroun is the active character...
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = HarounJump;       //Prime Haroun's jump audio clip
            gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();                  //Play Haroun's jump audio clip
        }

        HarounAnim.SetBool("Ground", false);            //Communicate jumping to Haroun's Animator
        RanaAnim.SetBool("Ground", false);              //Communicate jumping to Rana's Animator

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, 0);                //Zero out vertical velocity
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));                                             //Assign jump strength via AddForce on Y axis (Jumpforce Settings: Haroun|1670 Rana|4000)
        //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, jumpForce);      //Jump Strength via velocity on Y axis (Jumpforce Settings: Haroun|25 Rana|75)
    }
```

A bit more background on this: The player has two playable characters that are interchangeable at any time. One is named Haroun and the other Rana, hence the multiple character references. Haroun and Rana are their own separate objects with their own sprite renderers and colliders which are switched off and on with a boolean. Both the Rana and Haroun objects are child objects to the Character object that this script is attached to.

Comment: It may be that there's some piece of code changing the value of jumpForce somewhere, or the fact that the character is colliding with the ground is causing some weird bug. If it's the latter, make sure that nothing is changing the size/shape of the collider, and if all else fails, teleport the player slightly upward upon jumping.

Comment: Thank you. Teleporting the player slightly upwards seems to have worked. It's hard to tell since I can't make the glitch happen on command but I haven't seen it after testing it for a while and I would have expected to with the frequency I've seen it before. Only teleporting the character .5 units upward doesn't make a visual impact but does seem to fix the problem. This is the code is used to fix it: gameObject.transform.position = new Vector2(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y + .5f);

Comment: How much units high is your player ? Dont forget that later, this solution could cause issue when/if you will be making tunnels exactly the player height.